# Ordenar elementos de un archivo importado en python

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo un archivo con 10 elementos desordenados, deseo ordenar esos elementos en otro programa de manera ascendente y que me genere un archivo de salida con los datos ya ordenados.
Mi archivo con 10 elementos es éste, guardado en formato .py nombrado "T6"

```
def num(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):
print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)
```

num(4,3,6,1,2,8,5,7,9,10)

Y este es el de importar

```
import T6
band = False
while band == False:
band = True
for i in range(len(T6.num)-1):
      if (T6.num[i] > T6.num[i+1]:
         aux = T6.num[i]
         T6.num[i] = T6.num[i+1]
         T6.num[i+1] = aux
print(T6)
T6.num(4,3,6,1,2,8,5,7,9,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de leer tu comentario, he entendido que lo que quieres es tener en `T6` una variable con 10 números, y poder llamarla desde otro módulo y que aparezcan de forma ordenada.

Antes de nada, en tu código hay varias cosas raras, como por ejemplo que estás haciendo `len(T6.num)` y `T6.num` es una función por lo tanto te va a dar error. O que en el `if` te sobra un paréntesis...

Para poder hacer lo que pides puedes incluir la variable en el `return`. Te pongo un ejemplo:

**T6.py**

```
def num():
    numeros_desordenados = (4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 10)
    return sorted(numeros_desordenados)
```

**Importar.py**

```
import T6

print(T6.num())
```

Si no quieres que tu función devuelva eso, también puedes declararla como variable global:

**T6.py**

```
def num():
    global numeros_desordenados
    numeros_desordenados = (4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 10)
```

**Importar.py**

```
import T6

print(sorted(T6.numeros_desordenados))
```

De esta manera llamas directamente a la variable.

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por la respuesta, y segundo, lo que necesito es tener en T6 una funcion con 10 elementos desordenados; y en un módulo llamar esa función y ordenar los elementos

Comment: Si, es eso, gracias